# $\|\chi_A*\chi_B\|_{\mathbb L^\infty}\leq \min\{\lambda(A),\lambda(B)\}$

Tags: inequality, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, convolution

Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb R^d$ lebesgue measurable with finite Lebesgue measure and $f=\chi_A*\chi_B$

Show that $\|f\|_{L^\infty}\leq \min\{\lambda(A),\lambda(B)\}$

I know that $\|f\|_\infty\leq \sqrt{\lambda(A)}\sqrt{\lambda(B)}$ but this does not lead to the goal. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: **Hint:** $f(x)=\lambda \big(A\cap(x-B)\big)=\lambda \big((x-A)\cap B\big)$.